# filter вместо параметра callback Set.prototype.has

Tags: javascript

Никак не понимаю как работает этот код

```
function getCommon(a, b) {
  const isObject = o => typeof o === 'object';

  return Object.fromEntries(Object
      .keys(a)
      .filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(Object.keys(b)))
      .filter(k => a[k] === b[k] || isObject(a[k]) && isObject(b[k]))
      .map(k => [k, isObject(a[k]) ? getCommon(a[k], b[k]) : a[k]])
  );
}

console.log(getCommon({ a: 3, b: { x: 7 } }, { a: 4, b: { x: 7, y: 10 } }));
```

Результат

```
{
  "b": {
    "x": 7
  }
}
```

А если точнее это строка

```
.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(Object.keys(b)))
```

Я понимаю что filter ждет первым аргументом  функцию, а `Set.prototype.has` и есть функция, но тогда почему не работает этот мой код?

```
const a = [4,5,99,2];

const b = a.filter(Set.prototype.has) // Ошибкa
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Set.prototype.has` ожидает выполнения как метод экземпляра Set. То есть внутри него `this` должно равняться экземпляру Set. Что и достигается в вашем первом примере через второй параметр метода `filter()`, который задаёт `this` для функции-первого параметра. Чтобы ваш второй пример работал, нужно добавить второй параметр — экземпляр Set, в котором будет проверяться наличие элементов из фильтруемого массива:

```js
const a = [4, 5, 99, 2];

const b = a.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set([2, 4]));

console.log(b);
```

Того же эффекта можно достигнуть похожим способом:

```js
const a = [4, 5, 99, 2];

const b = a.filter(Set.prototype.has.bind(new Set([2, 4])));

console.log(b);
```

Или таким:

```js
const a = [4, 5, 99, 2];

const b = a.filter(function (num) { return this.has(num); }, new Set([2, 4]));

console.log(b);
```

Хотя это довольно вычурные способы. Наверное, понятнее для читателя было бы так:

```js
const a = [4, 5, 99, 2];

const set = new Set([2, 4]);
const b = a.filter(num => set.has(num));

console.log(b);
```

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ (+1). Но что значит: `Set.prototype.has` ожидает выполнения как метод экземпляра Set?

Comment: @Demon__ То, что внутри метода `Set.prototype.has` ключевое слово `this` должно быть объектом-экземпляром класса `Set` (то есть объектом, который возвращает выражение `new Set()`).

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, формально не только `new Set()` но и любых его наследников